# My question is about lists of words in a sentence

Tags: grammar, american-english, translation, editing

I came across an example of a translator position description, and I got confused about the meaning of the word "Research". Is this word related to the word "copy" or is it separate? Since the last word after the last comma has no "and".

Here it is:

> Research, write, edit French copy related to scientific technological exhibits and programs for visiting or virtual public. Produce small publications, write for websites, copyedit, translate English material with extensive scientific content into clear, interesting, understandable French copy and meet deadlines.

Answer (score 2):

In the above context "research" is one of the activities (in addition to "write" and "edit") that the person being recruited is expected to perform.  I would agree that the wording is somewhat confusing.

"Copy", in this context, is not a verb but rather a noun.  Basically, "French copy" is the document you're working on.